# add platform to ubuntu

Tags: environment-variables

I am new in Ubuntu (come from Windows 7), i want to know how can i add environment variable in Ubuntu, because the platform where i use exaggerate "To compile and run SCA composites with OW2 FraSCAti, you also have to set the FRASCATI_HOME system environment variable. FRASCATI_HOME has to point to the directory where the OW2 FraSCAti runtime distribution was extracted".

And how can i add it to my path "For conveniance, you can add FRASCATI_HOME/bin to your PATH variable to get the frascati command available in the PATH".
Please i'am new, could you explain me what i do step by step..

Answer (score 0):

You can add them in `/etc/environment`.

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Run:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/enviroment
```

- Add your variables. For example, if you had to initialize a variable named `FOO` to `some_value`, you'd

```
FOO="some_value"
```

- Save and exit